# Solution to the stochastic differential equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $X_o=x$, $dX_t=\frac{1}{X_t}dt+X_tdW_t$, $W_t$ is a brownian motion i am thinking of trying $Y_t=\frac{X_t^2}{2}$ and apply ito's lemma on $Y_t$

Comment: i think $Y_t=\frac{-X^2_t}{4}$ will do the trick

Comment: As a solution of what?

Comment: i mean trying $Y_t$ , and then apply ito's lemma on $Y_t$ and find $X_t$

Comment: You might wish to reconsider: solving an equation usually means expressing the unknown as an explicit function of the given, here the unknown is X and the given is W so you cannot express a solution as a function of X.

Comment: $W_t$ is brownian motion

Comment: Hmmm... in fact $(W_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ is a Brownian motion, $W_t$ is just a random variable. But I wonder what this has to do with my remark.

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to guess the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Let $Y_t = \mathrm{e}^{t- 2 W_t} X_t^2$. Then, applying Ito's lemma:
$$
  \mathrm{d} Y_t = \mathrm{e}^{t- 2 W_t} \mathrm{d} (X_t^2) + X_t^2 \mathrm{d} \mathrm{e}^{t- 2 W_t} + \mathrm{d} \mathrm{e}^{t- 2 W_t} \cdot \mathrm{d} (X_t^2) 
$$
Since $\mathrm{d} \mathrm{e}^{t- 2 W_t} = \mathrm{e}^{t- 2 W_t} \left( 3 \mathrm{d} t - 2 \mathrm{d} W_t \right)$ and $\mathrm{d}(X_t^2) = (X_t^2 + 2) \mathrm{d} t + 2 X_t^2 \mathrm{d} W_t$, we get:
$$
  \mathrm{d} Y_t = 2 \mathrm{e}^{t- 2 W_t} \mathrm{d} t
$$
Also, initial condition is $Y_0 = \mathrm{e}^{0 - 2 W_0}X_0^2 = x^2$. Therefore:
$$
   \mathrm{e}^{t- 2 W_t} X_t^2 = Y_t =  x^2 + \int_0^t 2 \mathrm{e}^{s - 2 W_s} \mathrm{d} s 
$$
This provides the solution:
$$
  X_t = \operatorname{sign}(x) \sqrt{ x^2 \mathrm{e}^{2 W_t - t} + 2 \mathrm{e}^{2 W_t - t} \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{s - 2 W_s} \mathrm{d} s  }
$$