# Solutions to stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm in a bit of trouble with my homework and was wondering if anyone could help me find the solutions to these two stochastic differential equations. Would really appreciate it! Thanks in advance! :)

```
1.
```

\begin{cases}
dX_t= \frac{b-X_t}{1-t}dt + dW_t\newline
X_0 = a \in \mathbb R
\end{cases} 
Where $b$ is a real constant.

```
2.
```

\begin{cases}
dY_t=\frac{1}{Y_t}dt + \alpha Y_tdW_t \newline
Y_0=y \in \mathbb R^++
\end{cases}
Where $a$ is a real constant.

```
3.
```

Verify which of the processes are affine

Comment: the first one is [Brownian bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) and I didn't get what 3. refer to

Comment: Thanks! Will check that out :)

Comment: Still haven't found out how to solve it. :( Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT For item 1**: Use [Ito lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D's_lemma) to verify that
$$
  \mathrm{d} \left( \frac{X_t-b}{1-t} \right) = \frac{1}{1-t} \mathrm{d} W_t
$$

**HINT for item 2**: See if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80118/solution-to-the-stochastic-differential-equation/80123#80123) answer of mine helps. But also think if you could match the constants so that the following expression has no diffusion component:
$$
   \mathrm{d}\left( Y_t^2 \exp\left( \lambda t + \mu W_t \right) \right)
$$